# Making blockquotes more visible

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

As title says: don't you agree that blockquotes are almost invisible?

I would suggest to improve the contrast, the margin or the indentation; maybe a shadow?

> Here is a blockquote as an example

Comment: @endolith I was referring to the main site quotes; anyway I think they are somehow related, so good edit :)

Comment: This seems to depend a lot on your monitor's settings (gamma?). On the screens of both my desktop and laptop they are/were fine. (Some people only discover after months that the title has a background image)

Comment: @stevenvh probably yes, even though I think that every laptop has contrast problems. But, while that makes the quote almost invisible, I think that the difference in background was/still-is very low by design...

Answer (score 4):

I have darkened the blockquote background color, also made the left border solid and darker. Should be significantly more visible than before. The change will be in the next prod build.

Comment: Perhaps it's the monitor I'm using, but on Meta.EE I can't still see clearly the blockquotes: can they be a bit darker too?